# How can I intercept EJB calls on client side without modifying application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, proxy, ejb

I have an EJB application. Remote clients which call server EJBs have some kind of proxies which do the networking, marshalling and unmarshalling. What if I want to replace these proxies by my own to change their behavior - e.g. to return fixed values, etc.?

Note that I do not want to change code of the original application.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard mechanism in EJB for client-side interceptors.

If you're using EJB over RMI-IIOP (only guaranteed for EJB 2.x or interfaces extending java.rmi.Remote), you might be able to configure your client-side ORB with an org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ClientRequestInterceptor.